# Group of radio buttons in different location

Tags: jsf, radio-button, richfaces

I am developing a JSF page where I have to place two radio buttons in different locations. First one will have two calendar components, and the next one will have an input text.
The components will be as follows (All components in a single row).
      
The problem is that the 2 radio buttons are not near each other but having components in between(if they were near each other I could use h:selectOneRadio).
Is there any way to achieve this in JSF or Richfaces?
Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and position the buttons where they need to be, but if you need to style each one individually that's not going to work.

Or you can use basic radio buttons with `<a4j:jsFunction>`, something like this:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(1)">
    <calendar> …

<input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(2)">
    <h:input… >

<a4j:jsFunction name="changeValue" >
    <a4j:param assignTo="#{bean.value}" name="value" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```